# Apache .htaccess: ErrorDocument and RewriteEngine not working together

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Please take a look at the following .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

With this setup, I am using `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');` in PHP to redirect to the error handling page and send the appropriate HTTP status code. The correct 404 status code is sent, but the browser shows a blank page and the access log shows `"GET /invalid-url/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Can anyone tell me how to make ErrorDocument work with Apache URL rewrites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer to my question is: I don't need to.
What I was trying to accomplish was a "404 redirect". That is, when requesting an invalid URL, redirect to the 404 document along with setting the "Status 404 Not found" header.
And I am not sure that's something I want, because invalid URLs should be marked with the 404 status code, not redirected.

Answer (score 5):

Yes declare 404 document after the Rewrite rules

It's normal your server do not push any 404 error, you're using a catchall regexp ((.*)) as the only rewrite rule.

But your issue is not really htaccess related. 
In php if you send 404 header the browser wont be redirected to the 404 page automaticaly, but you have to serve error page content yourself in PHP, as it is done by most frameworks with internal routing system.

Comment: Hi Benoit,

So you are saying that only sending a 404 header does not force Apache to server the content at the ErrorDocument URL.
If I serve the content from PHP, after setting the 404 header, I do get the 404 page displayed in the browser, but the address bar still shows the invalid URL, instead of /404/.
After giving some more thought, I guess that's not actually bad at all.

Comment: Hi, 

You're right, it does not seems bad if browser is not forwarded to real 404 page url. Apache does not redirect too using ErrorDocument declaration.
IMHO it is better this way : search engines crawler will forget the url responding with 404 http response code, and humans will see a nice 404 page instead of apache's default one or worse, page with errors on it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you define the Rewrite *before* the ErrorDocument.

Comment: Well, it didn't. I think Benoit is right. Only sending a 404 header from PHP with no content, does not force Apache to serve the content at the URL defined in my ErrorDocument. I hoped for that, but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: Nope, that won't help at all. Plus, changing the URL would break some things in my app.

Comment: I changed nothing in the RewriteRule it is same as your posted one.
I just edited your ErrorDocument line and it is correct for sure, see this link "http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument"

Comment: @Gaurav: I know this topic is old and dead, but for anyone else who might be reading... The ErrorDocument you used is correct for sure -- **for your environment**.  What do you suspect happens if "404.html" doesn't exist in bogdanvursu's environment?  As Benoit answered above, he was serving the 404 error but no redirection was occurring because the RewriteRule was rewriting to a valid url (index.php) and thus the ErrorDocument was never invoked.  The problem was that his index.php was returning a 404 header but not serving any content with it, thus the user saw nothing.